# Who evaluates Marie Curie Intra-European Fellowship proposals?

Tags: funding

Who are the evaluators of the Marie Curie Intra-European Fellowship proposals? Other academics ? How are they selected ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will find details on the evaluation process in the Guide for Applicants. The evaluators are experts (=researchers) in the field. They will be matched to the proposal according to their profile and to the abstract and keywords. They will for sure be in the general research area, but might not be in the exact same field of the proposal. It is (at least, officially) not possible to find out who evaluated the proposal afterwards, but you can find a list of former evaluators here:

http://cordis.europa.eu/fp7/experts_en.html

Answer (score 2):

*Who are the evaluators...?* I am. Along with a few hundred other people, of course! The evaluators ("experts" in EU jargon) are mostly academics from across Europe, with a decent number of scientists from industry, government, etc.

*How are they selected?* There is an open application process to become an EU H2020 expert. You fill out a form on the H2020 website, where you detail your scientific expertise, list your publications, grants etc. Then there is some selection process where, if your profile matches a vacancy on one of the evaluation panels, you get invited to be a panel member.